# Does coinbase API support USDT?

Tags: coinbase-api, tether

Sorry, I'm new here but my question is pretty basic.

I'm in need of suggestions for an API that can provide USDT addresses (any network is fine), and provide webhook notifications on transactions on these addresses.

Looking at coinbase API, they only mentioned bitcoin, bitcoin cash, litecoin and ethereum. But not sure if USDT is available.

Does anyone know if coinbase API supports USDT or any other API that could work for this purpose?